# É possível fazer duas chamadas de um método na mesma linha?

Tags: java

Meu programa tem duas classes, Texto e Frase. A instância teste é um objeto do tipo Texto que adiciona frases ao corpo do texto. Eu criei dois métodos com o nome adicionaFrase(), um recebe o objeto Frase como parâmetro e o outro recebe uma string. O método funciona quando eu coloco a segunda chamada do método na linha de baixo, mas retorna o erro "The method adicionaFrase(String) is undefined for the type String" quando eu coloco na mesma linha. É possível chamar o mesmo método duas vezes na mesma linha como foi feito no código abaixo?

```
teste.adicionaFrase(new Frase("Claramente conseguimos realizar estes feitos abstratos de diferentes maneiras.")).adicionaFrase("O importante é ter consciência da importância destes.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, basta fazer o seu metodo `adicionaFrase()` retornar sua propria classe `Text`, desta forma:

```
public Text adicionaFrase(Frase frase){
    // adicione a frase ao corpo do texto...

    return this;  // "this" para poder referenciar a propria classe
}
```